# Not getting response from controller in Spring MVC when using ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, eclipse, spring-mvc

I have problem with Ajax call controller in Spring MVC 3 using eclipse kepler ide. i have find some tutoruials on youtube and make project for studying. I have earlier problem too when i have Ajax call to controller, but after some time get work normally. My project is made in Spring MVC project, i have all request jars, just not hitting controller with Ajax call. thise is my conf files, controller method and ajax call in jquery

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

`<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.milan.springajax.controller" />
```

my controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getJSON/{firstName}/{lastName}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public  @ResponseBody
Contact findByName(@PathVariable("firstName") String first, @PathVariable("lastName") String last,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    Contact contact=contactService.findByName(first, last);
    return contact;
}
```

and ajax call who is located in jsp page in `<script>` tag

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    var first=$('#firstInput').val();
    var last=$('#lastInput').val();
    alert("button je stisnut " + first + " " + last); 

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:'${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getJSON/' + first + "/" + last,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(result) {
            var contact = "id: " + result.id +
                " | name : " + result.firstName + " " result.lastName + 
                " | age : " + result.age;


            $('#theJson').html(contact);

        },

         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Contact " + textStatus  + errorThrown + " !");
        }  in thise line i get warning that i miss semicolon ???
});

 });
});
```

and html elements in same jsp page

```
        <div>
            <label for="firstInput">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstInput">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="laststInput">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastInput">
        </div>
        <div id="theJson"></div>
        <button type="button" class="button" id="button">Fetch JSON</button>
```

does anyone else have problems with ajax call that not respong in eclipse using spring mvc , its like doesnt hitting right url adress when calling thise ajax method.

Comment: try using with browser and use firebug to inspect the request

Comment: What does your network console show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` from url `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getJSON/' + first + "/" + last`

It will not work in a JS file, instaed, replace directly for your app context:
 
`your-app/getJSON/' + first + "/" + last` or 
`/getJSON/' + first + "/" + last`

Comment: var contact = "id: " + result.id +
                " | name : " + result.firstName + " " result.lastName + 
                " | age : " + result.age; -- in thise line of code was a problem, i have forgot + to result.lastName hehe. thx all for helping